# Outlook API OAuth2 offline acces / permanent access using php

Tags: php, outlook, office365-apps, outlook-restapi

I followed the tutorial below to get mail using outlook api.
This works, but requires the user to login every time to give access. Is there a way to give permanent / offline access? Similar to how gmail api works (access to when your not at your keyboard)

https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php

Comment: maybe you could try [Exchange Web Services](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) - also, see [MS Office Dev Center: Start using web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900168(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely! In order to get offline access, you need to add the `offline_access` scope to your requested scopes. This will result in a refresh token being sent along with your access token. You can use the refresh token to get a new access token when the current one expires. See the "Refresh the Access Token" section of https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols/#oauth2-authorization-code-flow.

Comment: Thanks!  Would be great if you add this in your tutorial :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual string you would need to append to the scope:

`offline_access%20openid%20email%20profile`

A basic example of a scope:

`"openid+https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.read+https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fcalendars.read+offline_access%20openid%20email%20profile"`