# Oauth2 url and offline access scope for microsoft outlook rest api

Tags: php, rest, oauth-2.0, msdn, outlook-restapi

Have some serious doubt as to what to use when implementing Outlook REST API for processing mails of users...

**Regarding OAuth2 URL:**

the [php client example](https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-tutorial) specifies "https://login.microsoftonline.com"

but the [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631818.aspx) specifies "https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf"

**Regarding OAUTH2 Scopes:**

Also regarding the Scope for enabling our app to use offline access for accessing the user's data anytime,

The [Stack overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483796/outlook-api-oauth2-offline-acces-permanent-access-using-php) Specifies "offline_access" scope

whereas [msdn scope docs1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631845.aspx) and [msdn scope docs2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh243646.aspx#core) Specifies "wl.offline_access" scope

I'm confused... will the support be dropped for any of the above spec attributes at any point of time? will my app stop working if they stop supporting it or is any of the above mentioned spec attributes expired/deprecated?

Plzzzz someone clarify this to me

Comment: when including `wl.offline_access` scope in outlook rest api oauth2 flow, the microsoft login page reported an error, but after removing the `wl.offline_access` scope, the normal flow continued... So `offline_access` would be the right scope...

Comment: The guys who downvoted this question at-least leave a comment why it deserved to be downvoted!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook REST API is tested and supported with the Azure OAuth implementation, so I would definitely go with the `login.microsoftonline.com` and `offline_access`. The other docs you are citing are part of the Live SDK, which I believe would not work for Office 365 users.